# Help with simple Linq count statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
var q = dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.userID == UserID);
q.OrderByDescending(c => c.dateSubmitted);
```

This works fine, but I also need to return the count of records returned from `tblHelpCentreReplies` where `QuestionID` equals `tblHelpCentreQuestions.ID`.  This is easy enough for me in SQL, can someone show me how this is done in LINQ to SQL?

### Edit

I've got as far as this:

```
var q = 
from question in dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
join replies in dc.tblHelpCentreReplies on question.ID
    equals replies.ticketID
where question.userID == UserID
orderby question.dateSubmitted descending
select new { question, replies.Count() };
```

But replies.Count() throws:

> Invalid anonymous type member
>   declarator. Anonymous type members
>   must be declared with a member
>   assignment, simple name or member
>   access.

Comment: this should be: new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count()}

Comment: @dh thanks, still get the error though `'CryatalCommon.tblHelpCentreReply' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'CryatalCommon.tblHelpCentreReply' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: this is because you use join which is inner join but what you want is an aggregate function over your replies table. see the query in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the linq query would look like this:

```
var q =
    dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.
        Where(question => question.userID == UserID).
        OrderByDescending(question => question.dateSubmitted).
        GroupJoin(
            dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
            question => question.ID,
            replies => replies.ticketID,
            (question, replies) => new {Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count()});
```

**update**
if you have a relation mapping than that could be a bit easier

```
var q =
    dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.
        Where(question => question.userID == UserID).
        OrderByDescending(question => question.dateSubmitted).
        Select(question => new {Question = question, RepliesCount = question.Replies.Count()});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than you might imagine :-)

```
var q = 
    from question in dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
    where question.userID == UserID
    orderby question.dateSubmitted desc
    select new { question, question.Replies.Count() };
```

Comment: Thanks, bit confused, there doesn't seem to be any reference to tblHelpCentreReplies?

Comment: @Tom: Take good care into designing your model. When you have the proper primary-foreign key releations in your database, the designer will most of the time figure this out for you correctly. When you have the proper relations, there must be a relation between a questions and the replies table. You can rename your objects and releations in the designer. Possibly it is not named `Replies` but something like `tblHelpCentreReplies` (which is of course a yucky name to have in your domain).

Comment: thanks, when you say proper PK->FK relationships, I have PK's defined in my SQL database, should I just need to create associations in my Linq to SQL designer (dbml file)?

Comment: @Tom: Yes you should, or when possible, just remove the tables from the designer and drag them on again. the designer will figure it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = 
from question in dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
join replies in dc.tblHelpCentreReplies on question.ID equals replies.ticketID
where question.userID == UserID
orderby question.dateSubmitted descending
select new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count()};
```